# Kafka can not access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a problem installing Kafka on  windows.
I installed  kafka cluster of 3 instances in 3 differents servers (each server contain one kafka and zookeeper )
all work well, but when an instance kafka stop (or fail ) , when i try to restart this instance .
I have this error message:

```
`[2017-11-10 15:17:53,999] INFO [ThrottledRequestReaper-Fetch]: Starting 
(kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledRequestReaper)
[2017-11-10 15:17:53,999] INFO [ThrottledRequestReaper-Produce]: Starting 
(kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledRequestReaper)
[2017-11-10 15:17:53,999] INFO [ThrottledRequestReaper-Request]: Starting 
(kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledRequestReaper)
[2017-11-10 15:17:54,109] INFO Loading logs. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2017-11-10 15:17:54,171] WARN Found a corrupted index file due to 
requirement failed: Corrupt index found, index file (C:\Tools\Kafka\kafka-
logs\hubone.dataCollect.orbiwise.ArchiveQueue-0\00000000000000000015.index) 
has non-zero size but the last offset is 15 which is no larger than the base 
offset 15.}. deleting C:\Tools\Kafka\kafka-
logs\hubone.dataCollect.orbiwise.Arch`iveQueue-
0\00000000000000000015.timeindex, C:\Tools\Kafka\kafka-
logs\hubone.dataCollect.orbiwise.ArchiveQueue-0\00000000000000000015.index, 
and C:\Tools\Kafka\kafka-logs\hubone.dataCollect.orbiwise.ArchiveQueue-
0\00000000000000000015.txnindex and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log)
[2017-11-10 15:17:54,171] ERROR There was an error in one of the threads 
**during logs loading: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: 
C:\Tools\Kafka\kafka-logs\hubone.dataCollect.orbiwise.ArchiveQueue-
0\00000000000000000015.timeindex: The process cannot access the file because 
it is being used by another process.**
(kafka.log.LogManager)
[2017-11-10 15:17:54,171] FATAL [Kafka Server 1], Fatal error during 
KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Tools\Kafka\kafka-
logs\hubone.dataCollect.orbiwise.ArchiveQueue-
0\00000000000000000015.timeindex: The process cannot access the file because 
it is being used by another process.

at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$loadSegmentFiles$3.apply(Log.scala:318)
at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$loadSegmentFiles$3.apply(Log.scala:279)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
at kafka.log.Log.loadSegmentFiles(Log.scala:279)
at kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:383)
at kafka.log.Log.<init>(Log.scala:186)
at kafka.log.Log$.apply(Log.scala:1609)
at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$loadLogs$2$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(LogManager.scala:172)
at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$$anon$1.run(CoreUtils.scala:57)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

when i delete kafka-logs , the offsets are corrupted .
could you help me to fix this problem ?

i opened an issue in kafka :
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6200

Comment: Did you check what process keeps the ownership of this file?

Comment: The process is "java.exe" , i can't kill the process , i can see it in the task manager  but when i ktry kill it with command "taskill /pid xxx /F /T" , it tell me that can't kill it and the reason is that there is no running  instance of  the task .

Comment: So it looks like your process didn't finish correctly, you need to find a way to kill it & restart

Comment: I reboot the server and every thing work fine .

Comment: I think it is related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1194 as well

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue.
I simply deleted the files in ..\tmp**kafka-logs**\ directory.
Then i restarted the services and it worked like a charm.

Comment: That solves the issue but doesn't resolve the cause

Comment: @yassine, not sure if this is still relevant with zookeeper gone. Please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was resolved after emptying the recycle bin on windows after deleting logs from tmp and log directories